# Uninstalling packages with dependencies with pip

Tags: python, pip, package

Is there a way to uninstall a package and all their dependencies through pip rather than uninstalling each dependency from my venv one by one? Or erasing my entire pip installs and then reinstalling the packages and dependencies that I want?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you may use [pip-autoremove](https://github.com/invl/pip-autoremove)

this tool can remove package and its dependencies.

Comment: `Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<frozen runpy>", line 198, in _run_module_as_main
  File "<frozen runpy>", line 88, in _run_code
  File "D:\ProgramData\anaconda3\envs\vector\Scripts\pip-autoremove.exe\__main__.py", line 4, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pip_autoremove'`

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a way to uninstall a package and all their dependencies through pip rather than uninstalling each dependency from my venv one by one?

I use this bash function

```
pipdepuninstall () 
{ 
    pip install -q pipdeptree
    pipdeptree -p$1 -fj | jq ".[] | .package.key" | xargs pip uninstall -y
}
```

This removes all dependencies of a package, and the package itself.

```
$ pip install Flask
$ pipdepuninstall Flask
```

Comment: What if one of the packages you removed is a dependency of another package that is still installed?